# Web Parts - Unable to Collapse a List Group by Default

Tags: web-part, grouping, web-part-page

First question on this site and this is probably stupid and I'm overlooking something glaringly obvious but here is goes.

**Background**

I just recently rebuilt our site in SharePoint Online (2016) from SP07. I used a web parts page to manage our personnel files system - this pulls both scanned physical documents from a document library and various other data from several lists into one central location. There is a staff selector web part with a data connector to all of the others - a staff member is selected and all other web parts are filtered by that staff member, showing only that information.

**Situation**

In SP07, when I created the web part views, this was done by grouping the list/library by staff member and then only showing one group per page. I had the option to collapse these groups by default (I have the same option in SPO). Due to large amounts of data - you can imagine that users may not want everything expanded by default - they would only open (expand) what they need. This worked beautifully in SP07 but in SPO, no matter what I do, all the web part groups expand by default (despite this being set to collapse in the view being used).

To be clear, we are not talking about minimizing/collapsing the web parts themselves but only the groupings used in their views.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested with an account other than your own. If I remember correctly SharePoint "remembers" if your groups were expanded or collapsed and overrides the default setting, but other users will see everything collapsed if that is the default for the view and they have not used that view before.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's expanded for everyone. And if I try to collapse each WP group individually, they just revert back to expanded once the page refreshes (i.e. it doesn't remember the setting).